# Sticky menu while scrolled WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to display the menu hanging while the top advertisment section and logo section is scrolled down and it must be sticked on the top. I am customizing the theme. In the theme there is no such property but I want it on my site.

I have tried using jQuery syntax but didn't work out.

Comment: You try any plugins

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).